# API displaying undefined in HTML and not the value

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, undefined

I'm not too sure why this is happening but here is my code

```
<div id="list">

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $.ajax({
            type:"get",
            url:"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://41.78.37.222/dev/api.php?action=list",
            success: function(data){
            result="";
            for(i in data){
            result+="MAKE: "+data[i].make+" // TYPE: "+data[i].type+"<br>";
            }
            $("#list").html(result);
            }
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Please note I am using https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ infront of my API URL to get rid if CORS Policy error (temporarily). The API URL is http://41.78.37.222/dev/api.php?action=list

When running my code, it displays:

MAKE: undefined // TYPE: undefined

in the HTML instead of something like:

MAKE: BMW 320i (E90) 2009 Facelift // TYPE: Standard

Comment: Your get api returns this: 
Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with

As API is not working, no one solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the use of the `data` variable.  The code assumes that `data` is an object - in fact it is a string.

When the code executes `for(i in data)`, you are stepping through each character in the string.

To resolve the issue, the string in `data` needs to be converted to an object using `JSON.parse()`.  The resulting object can then be enumerated in the same way as before as can be seen in the working snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:"get",
    url:"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://41.78.37.222/dev/api.php?action=list",
    success: function(data){
    result="";
    dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
    for (i in dataObj) {
      item = dataObj[i];
      result+="MAKE: "+item.make+" // TYPE: "+item.type+"<br>";
    }
    $("#list").html(result);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">

</div>
```